# DARLE FORMATO A MI ENLACE QUE SE COMPARTIRA EN FACEBOOK

Tags: php, html, facebook

Al momento de compartir un enlace de mi web a facebook me aparece asi, me muestra la informacion de mi index.php, pero yo quiero que se visualice la informacion de otra pagina, el enlace cumple con su funcion, es decir, si redirije a la pestaña que deseo mostrar.

[image: asi se ve en facebook]

Y me gustaria que se viera de la siguiente manera 
[image: Este es el ejemplo]

este es mi codigo que tengo en mi head de la pagina que deseo se muestra dicha informacion en el enlace

```
<head>
  <title>My 50 Words</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="css/stilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <meta property="og:url"           content="http://atlanix.com.mx/proyecto/publicacion.php" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="article" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="MY 50 WORDS" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="QUE ONDA QUE PEDO LOCOS" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://atlanix.com.mx/proyecto/images/logo.jpg" />
</head>
```

Comment: fijate de entrar al [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) y refrescar la metadata, si hay algún error te avisa ( seguramente tenga cacheado una prueba )

Comment: Abrí una publicación en tu sitio y encontré muchos errores de marcado, como etiquetas meta al inicio, además de que no aparecen las etiquetas open graph.